# What is the precise statement of the rule "LOCC cannot create new entanglement"?

Tags: quantum-information, quantum-entanglement

I think that the statement "LOCC cannot create new entanglement [between spatially separated regions $A$ and $B$]" is good enough when only two parties are involved in the process. However, if we involve a third party $C$ then I'm not sure what is the precise formulation.

For example, if $A$, $B$, and $C$ share a ${\rm GHZ}$ state then no two of the three locations are mutually entangled. However, the local operation of measuring their qubit in $X$ basis at any one of the three locations (say $C$) will get the rest of the two locations (say $A$ and $B$) entangled:

$$\vert \rm{GHZ}\rangle=\frac{\vert 000\rangle+\vert111\rangle}{\sqrt{2}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\bigg(\vert+\rangle\otimes\frac{\vert 00\rangle+\vert11\rangle}{\sqrt{2}}+\vert-\rangle\otimes\frac{\vert 00\rangle-\vert 11\rangle}{\sqrt{2}}\bigg)$$

Of course, it would be probabilistic as to which one of the two possible entangled states (i.e., $\frac{\vert{00}\rangle\pm\vert 11\rangle}{\sqrt{2}}$) it is that $A$ and $B$ end up sharing. However, this can also be "remedied" by $1$ bit of classical communication between $C$ and $B$ and $1$ local operation at $B$:  $C$ tells $B$ the outcome of their measurement and $B$ applies a $Z$ gate on their qubit if the outcome of $C$'s measurement was "$-$".

So, what is a general statement of the rule "LOCC cannot create new entanglement [between spatially separated regions $A$ and $B$]" that would also apply to this kind of situations? I intuitively understand what is going on: in the GHZ state, $AB$ as a whole are entangled with $C$ and it is this entanglement that is being transferred from being between $AB$ and $C$ to being between $A$ and $B$. However, if I literally apply the principle I quoted above, I'd be surprised because there was no entanglement between $A$ and $B$ -- and yet, at the end of a few LOCCs, they are now entangled.

Comment: I don't understand the question. You observed that you can transform a GHZ to a Bell state via LOCC. The operation you applied is an LOCC with respect to the $A:BC$ partition, and it results in a state that is *not* entangled (wrt this partition), because the final Bell state is only in $BC$.

Comment: @glS Yes, but what I'm unsure about is how to think of it in terms of the pairwise $A:B$, $B:C$, $A:C$ partitions. All operations are LOCC w.r.t. each partition (?) and yet, the $B:C$ partition starts out unentangled and ends up entangled? I'm not suggesting having observed a paradox here, just to be clear! :) I'm just trying to verbalize what I don't understand about the definition of LOCC and about the principle that LOCC cannot create new entanglement -- in the case of multipartite systems.

Comment: everything should work wrt all partitions. But in the $B:C$ bipartition the operation you refer to is not an LOCC, because it involves measuring/doing something on $A$, so it's just not properly defined on the reduced state on $B:C$. So you need to describe the situation in $A:B$, $A:C$, or $A:BC$, and in all these you start with entanglement and up with no entanglement. More generally, LOCCs deal with bipartite entanglement. Entanglement in multipartite sys is much more complex; you'll need generalisations of LOCCs to deal with it, and there isn't a unique way to quantify it

Comment: @glS Thanks! That makes sense. I think this is what I was trying to think but your comment made it a bit clearer in my head: how to characterize the communications from outside a bipartite system vis-a-vis its effect on the entanglement within the bipartite system when the bipartite system has a mixed state? I suppose it's much more complex than a simple bumper-sticker rule like you suggest. Can you suggest some place where I can read up on this? I'd be glad to accept a compilation of your comments as the answer :)